# Is every nonempty set that bounded below has an infimum where the set is not necessary a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus

Every nonempty set that bounded below has an infimum if the set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but if the set is not subset of $\mathbb{R}$, does the statement still hold?

Comment: What does "bounded below" (or "infimum") mean if it is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0):

You need the overall set to be complete like $\Bbb R$, but there are other sets where this applies.  In $\Bbb Q$ the set $\{x|x^2 \gt 2\}$ is bounded below by $1$ but has no inf.  One example would be $\Bbb R \cup \{c\}$ where we define that $c$ is greater than any element of $\Bbb R$

Comment: I mean a set A is a subset of X, A bounded below and the inf is in X, so in this sense, any subset of Q is not bounded below.